# Why doesn't the width option work properly

Tags: 3d, asymptote

I get the following error:

```
Overfull \hbox (7.60025pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--31
```

I code on Overleaf.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\hypersetup{
    pdfstartview=FitH,
    }
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\begin{asy}[width=\linewidth]
settings.outformat="png";
settings.prc=true;

import graph3;
import three;
size(0,200);
currentprojection=perspective(2,0,0);

draw(unitsphere);

\end{asy}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label2}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i 've deleted the line, now i get the same error

Comment: well actually \hypersetup is sometimes defined (as asymptote loads in hyperref sometimes, but imho you should better not rely on it, load it explicitly). It looks as if width doesn't set the exact width of the png, try the `viewportwidth` key (but the documentation is not very clear about what the keys really do).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer unfortunately `viewportwidth` does not scale the content of asy-environment (`viewportwidth` allows to obtain free space on the side in an interactive mode). `viewportwidth` leads further to a similar error.